# Reading binary output from a shell script in Node.js

Tags: node.js

I need to execute a shell command from my Node.js script, read its output and terminate that program after a certain number of bytes is read. (More precisely, I want to do a partial download of a file via `smbget`).

The most obvious approach, I guess, is to use `childprocess.spawn()`, buffer the output manually and simply `kill()` the process when sufficient data was read.

And this works nicely, except that I looks a bit clunky. So instead I wanted to be clever (TM) and use `head`. So I wired everything up as indicated in the docs to [child_process](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) (or, somewhat more conveniently, using [procstreams](https://npmjs.org/package/procstreams)) to produce a pipeline equivalent to `cat /dev/urandom | head --bytes=10`. Alas, everything goes up in flames like so:

```
events.js:72
     throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
             ^

Error: read ECONNRESET
    at errnoException (net.js:883:11)
    at Pipe.onread (net.js:539:19)
```

probably because `head` just clubs the stream to death, and I couldn't find a way to catch or otherwise handle that error (although that could just be because I'm a node n00b :).

Alternatively, I could do the following:

```
var cmd = 'cat /dev/urandom | head --bytes=100';
childprocess.exec(cmd, function (err, stdout, stderr) {
    // ...
});
```

except that I can't access the raw (binary) data anymore. When I call

```
fs.writeFileSync('foo.dat', stdout);
```

the stream will be utf8 encoded, resulting in the file being around 180 bytes instead of the expected 100 bytes.

This can be circumvented by passing a second parameter to `exec`:

```
{ encoding: 'binary' }
```

Unfortunately, the docs say that this is deprecated.

What is the correct way of doing this? Or do I absolutely need to buffer myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically you should be able to pass 'buffer' as an encoding and have it output a Buffer specifically, but looks like that's not the case. I've [opened a ticket for it](https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/5833) and that should be fixed before v0.12 release.

For the time being feel free to use binary encoding. It was only sort of deprecated, but will never go away. In v0.11 [it received some love](http://github.com/joyent/node/commit/642ea2b) and is now synonymous with latin1 encoding. Which is officially supported by v8, so support won't be going away any time soon.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I think I'll just stick to "binary" then for the time being.